# Keeping a reference for a List<T> without knowing T?

Tags: c#, unity-container

**Clarification:** The goal is to have my UIPList 1.Able to watch any ObservableList where T is iUIP or one of its inheritors, 2. Able to draw the UIPrefab button connected to that iUIP in the list, and 3. Able to change what list it's watching at any time (and only be watching the one list).

I can draw the gui buttons and get that first watch working (with the hacky code below), but there's no way to store the reference in UIPList so I can unsubscribe from that list when I want to watch something else. I can't make it into "UIPList" (which would make it possible to store a reference) without losing the third ability mentioned above.

I'm now trying having the menus (who know what UIPLists and ObservableLists are involved) take care of unsubscribing when the contents change, but ideally I can just pass a ObservableList to UIPList and it'll know how to watch it, draw the gui, and unsubscribe when it gets a new list to watch by itself.

**Original Post:**
I have `UIPList` which is supposed to watch a `ObservableList<T> where T:iUIP`. (`iUIP` meaning a class that has a button that can be drawn in a `UIPList`).

The problem is I can't store a local reference to the list, since it could be `ObservableList<iUIP>` OR it could be `ObservableList<Character>` OR `ObservableList<Organization>` or so on (other classes inheriting `iUIP`).

I cant use a `ObservableList<iUIP>` on `UIPList` as a reference, since I might want to watch a list which can't be cast to `ObservableList<iUIP>` despite character inheriting from iUIP, so there's no way to store a local reference to the list `UIPList` is supposed to watch.

I use a `SetWatchList<T>(ObservableList<T> list)` method on `UIPList` to take a list to watch, but since there's no reference to the original list, when I want to change what the `UIPList` is watching I don't have the reference I need to unsubscribe from the *previous* list.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class UIPList : MonoBehaviour
{
public GUIManager GUIManager;
public UILabel Title;
public UITable Contents;

//  ObservableList<T>.ListChangedEventHandler subscribedChangeEvent;

public void WatchList<T>(ObservableList<T> list) where T: iUIP
{
    this.subscribedChangeEvent = list.ListChanged;
    list.ListChanged += DrawUIPList;//TODO make always clear prev?
    DrawUIPList<T>(list);
}

//dont have a reference to the old list to know what to stop watching!
//  public void StopWatchList<T>(ObservableList<T> list) where T: iUIP
//  {
//      list.ListChanged -= DrawUIPList;
//  }

// Use this for initialization
protected void Start()
{
    this.GUIManager = GUIManager.Find;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
}


void DrawUIPList<T>(object source, ObservableList<T>.ListChangedEventArgs e) where T : iUIP
{
    DrawUIPList<T>(e.list);
}
void DrawUIPList<T>(ObservableList<T> list) where T:iUIP
{
    //todo AddComponentMenu/RemoveItem/adjut ReadOnlyCollectionBase changed UIPs
    ClearContents();
    this.Contents.Reposition();
    foreach (T uip in list)//TODO make this automatic, not need each one
    {
        //          Debug.Log("Adding UIP:" + child.name);
        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPCorporationButton)
            UIPCorporationButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Corporation));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPCompanyButton)
            UIPCompanyButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Company));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPAssetButton)
            UIPAssetButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Asset));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPIndButton)
            UIPIndButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Industry));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPSecButton)
            UIPSecButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Sector));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPOperativeButton)
            UIPOperativeButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Operative));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPAgencyButton)
            UIPAgencyButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Agency));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPBrokerButton)
            UIPBrokerButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Broker));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPCellButton)
            UIPCellButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Cell));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPMissionButton)
            UIPMissionButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Mission));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPObjectiveButton)
            UIPObjectiveButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Objective));

        if (uip.UIPButton is UIPChallengeButton)
            UIPChallengeButton.Create(this.Contents.gameObject, (uip as Challenge));


    }
    //this.Contents.Reposition();
    this.Contents.repositionNow = true;
}

public void ClearContents()
{
//      this.Contents.children.children.Clear();
    int count = this.Contents.transform.childCount;     
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {           
        GameObject.Destroy(this.Contents.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);         
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "can't be cast to ObservableList<iUIP> despite character inheriting from iUIP"   how is that possible?

Comment: Basically, while Character can be held in a iUIP reference, you can't do the same thing with List<T>. Technically I can take each object from list<Character> and put them in a new list<iUIP>, but that's a NEW list and won't reflect the changes happening to the one I'm trying to watch.

Answer (score 2):

Make the entire class generic

```
public class UIPList<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : iUIP
```

Then you *can* store a reference to the list.  This better encapsulates what the list actually is.

Don't forget to also remove the generic constraints from your methods

```
public void WatchList(ObservableList<T> list)
```

Comment: This would remove the UIPList's ability to watch any variety of list though, so I could no longer change the watchlist from <iUIP> to <character> to <organization> etc, as the active menu required. I'd have to destroy and remake the UIPLists any time they changed contents to a different type.
The main problem seems to be where I could use a iUIP ref to hold a Character or Organization, the list<iUIP> cannot hold list<Character> or list<Organization>...

Comment: ALSO:Just realized Unity won't show UIPList<T> in the inspector which means the references to the actual GUI element from the menu are broken.

Comment: *"I'd have to destroy and remake the UIPLists any time they changed contents to a different type"* - that sounds like a reasonable behavior.